# dojox mvc at() target

Tags: model-view-controller, dojo

I've created a sandbox with a demonstration of binding UI components to both data and state:  http://dojo-sandbox.net/public/51073/1

It's my plan to generate code from a page definition creating a page-level widget which is templated.  This widget will have its own scope, where the model and state will reside, which I am trying to simulate in the sandbox by way of the Page object.

The sandbox is working because the Page object is in the global state, which appears to be the default context for object resolution in mvc binding.

However the plan is to have a view widget supporting each page with both the Model and State contained within the widget's scope.  The generated template for the view would be bound to both the Model and the State.  I can establish the source via the 'target' property, but when the same UI component must be bound to two different models, one for value and one for state, the single source doesn't support this.

The Model data will come to me from the back-end, and the State data is derived via the State.Execute method once the Model data is present.

I've taken a look at the 'rel:' parameter of at(), but don't see how to leverage this syntax within a specific context, ie my view widget's scope.  It seems to be working fine for the default global scope.

Is there a standard way to direct the data-dojo-props value binding at one source, and the data-mvc-bindings for attributes at another?  Or, more precisely, what is the at('rel:') syntax which will support specifying the context of the relation, and not rely on the 'target' of the widget or containing widget?

If there is no way to specify the 'target' at this level, I will generate more logic in the Execute method to specifically set the html attribute on the component during state compilation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data-mvc-bindings` is for allowing non-widgets use dojox/mvc/at. If a widget is declared for an element `data-dojo-props` is the one for use instead.

If `target` is specified via `data-dojo-props` or `data-mvc-bindings`, it’ll be set eventually to the `widget.target`. `”rel:”` syntax looks for a widget having `.target` up in DOM tree.

It means that one “group” cannot have more than one "relative binding target”, in case it’s one of your questions. You can have a “scope object” that contains pointers to more than one models and use it as a “relative binding target”, that may serve a similar purpose:

```
<div data-dojo-type="dijit/_WidgetBase"
 data-dojo-props="target: {model0: model0, model1: model1}">
    <input type="text"
     data-dojo-type="dijit/form/TextBox"
     data-dojo-props="value: at('rel:model0', 'value'),
                      disabled: at('rel:model1', 'disabled')" />
</div>
```

A working example can be found at http://jsfiddle.net/asudoh/M3bRC/. Hope these help.

Best, - Akira

Comment: Thanks @asudoh

The multiple models in the single mvc/Group target was the key.

I've updated my approach in http://dojo-sandbox.net/public/7917e/0

I'll also move to data-dojo-props when there is a widget in play.